# laravel Multiple select form get array

Tags: php, laravel, multi-select

Hello im using this code for a multiple select form

```
{{ Form::select('language', $language, null, array('multiple' => true, 'multiple class' => 'chosen-select form-control')); }}
```

but this code only send the last input to database, ive searched and found to attach this [ ] to the name like this

```
{{ Form::select('language[]', $language, null, array('multiple' => true, 'multiple class' => 'chosen-select form-control')); }}
```

But with this code i cant save the data, did you know why? 
Thank you

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24768327/laravel-4-sending-the-input-back-on-a-failed-submission/24768453#24768453

Comment: Thank you for the link, im using another script but i need it in the future

Answer (score 2):

The name attribute in the html tag must have the brackets; however, when you grab the input in your controller you must not include the brackets.

View:

```
{{ Form::select('language_ids[]', $languagesArray, defaultSelectionsArray, ['multiple' => 'true']) }}
```

Controller:

```
public function store() {
    $languageIds = Input::get('language_ids');
}
```